# Managing store opening hours in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP to build a store directory. I have a stores table and a stores opening table. A store has many store_opening_hours. This way there is the possibility of looking up stores that are open at a particular time.

stores

- id
- name
- description

store_opening_hours

- id
- store_id
- day_of_week
- time_open
- time_closed

I have baked the basic CRUD functionality for the stores and for store_opening hours. However, I would like to be able to edit the opening hours for a the week while editing the store details.

I'm not sure I have gone about this the correct way in order to achieve this. Can anyone point me in the right direction for editing the hasMany records from the stores edit method?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using CakePHP 2.0 (if not I suggest to use 2.0 anyways) check this page

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

It explains exactly what you want to do.